# How do i run my simple backbone app from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

[Here is my app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voxbM.png) 
I am trying to run simple backbone app which i downloaded from one site from nodeJS ,I wasn't able to do so this is my first attempt in starting a backbone app standalone

Comment: Maybe explain what is the problem, what you tried, what you observe etc

Answer (score 3):

If you want to serve the files you can install http-server with
`npm install -g http-server` in your command line. Then go to the directory and type `http-server` it should run the files on a certain loop address with a port number